# "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." error in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have this custom class which extends EventDispatcher

```
private var assetsManager:AssetManager;
```

And this running on creationComplete

```
GeneralUtils.parentComponent = this;                          
this.assetsManager.addEventListener(AssetEvent.ASSETS_LOADED,OnAssetsLoaded);
this.LoadConfigFile();
```

I'm getting 1009 errors on the second line. I've been looking at this for a while and can't figure out what it can't find. The OnAssetsLoaded function is there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you're not creating the assetManager object. You need to explicitly create it

```
 assetsManager = new AssetManager ();
```

before trying to attach listeners to it